# LAN access with PulseSecure split VPN disabled

Tags: vpn, split-tunnel

Context: corporate network, win10 PCs. Devs frequently need simultaneous access to a remote network through PulseSecure VPN and to computers on LAN. Policymakers can't be convinced to enable split VPN.

One fragile workaround found is to use an USB->LAN dongle, register the USB appliance under VirtualBox and access LAN through VirtualBox.

Could you suggest a more robust / less overhead method?

Answer (score 1):

Point is:

> Policymakers can't be convinced to enable split VPN.

Any attempt to circumvent **is contrary to your corporate rules** and would qualify for job termination.

Be smart. Ask others in your company for support. Then talk to the policymaker's supervisor. Explain the situation and why it is better for the company to implement a split route VPN from your point of view. (eg. provide business reasons)

From my experience, there are a couple of reasons where a split route VPN should **not** be realized. (Not everything that is technically feasible makes sense in every company). Those reasons should be communicated accordingly.

In almost all cases, it can be explained very precisely why it is not implemented. Listen carefully to all these reasons. Ask yourself if some of them can be remedied and how you may be able to help achieving this.

If the supervisor cannot explain why it cannot be implemented, update your CV and start searching a company that suits the interests of a developer better.